# C++ windows.h(WIN32_FIND_DATA and HANDLE) Android equivalent

Tags: android, c++, ios

I have a C++ library that uses the windows.h header.
I'm trying to port this library to Android & IOS (so a Shared Library).
I've searched for replacements for the windows.h header(in particular the WIN32_FIND_DATA and HANDLE equivalents) but with no luck.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: They don't exists for those platforms.  Remove them and any code that uses them.  You will need to re-write / redesign the code.

Comment: The C++ equivalent for those is the [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library. You could port the code to use that.